# Why transcoded video output duration is differs from input video?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Original duration (input video) was 0:00:15.093

One of the transcoded output video duration is 0:00:15.323

Is this expected?

Kindly refer the attached screenshot and provide your inputs.

[image]

Comment: It's due to the different frame rates those videos have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mewa! What is the correct frame rate for this input video??